# How do I configure x11vnc.service to run x11vnc as root?

Tags: 20.04, vnc, remote

I'd like to access my "real" display remotely. Basically use my macbook to pilot what I see on the display of my local server. My goal is that the same image is duplicated: in the actual display of the linux box and via VNC on my macbook. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and it's November 2020.

As [this dude](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-ubuntu-18-04-connect-to-login-screen-over-vnc/) says very poetically "I installed nomachine and it took the grand total of 2 minutes to setup and it works as I wanted".

The link also explains you must switch to lightdm. Fine.

if I try:

```
/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess
```

I get:

```
22/11/2020 20:23:51 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 4745
22/11/2020 20:23:51 -auth guess: failed for display=':0'
```

if I try:

```
/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0
```

I get:

```
22/11/2020 20:29:26 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 5167
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key22/11/2020 20:29:26 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
22/11/2020 20:29:26 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
22/11/2020 20:29:26 ***************************************
22/11/2020 20:29:26 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)

*** x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":0", it cannot continue.
*** There may be "Xlib:" error messages above with details about the failure.
```

if I try:

```
sudo /usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0
```

I get:

```
22/11/2020 20:30:22 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 5171
No protocol specified
22/11/2020 20:30:22 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
22/11/2020 20:30:22 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
No protocol specified

22/11/2020 20:30:22 ***************************************
22/11/2020 20:30:22 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)

*** x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":0", it cannot continue.
*** There may be "Xlib:" error messages above with details about the failure.
```

Finally if I try:

```
sudo /usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess
```

I get:

```
22/11/2020 20:32:24 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 5188
xauth:  file /root/.Xauthority does not exist
22/11/2020 20:32:24 -auth guess: using 'XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0' for disp=':0'
22/11/2020 20:32:24 Using X display :0
22/11/2020 20:32:24 rootwin: 0x583 reswin: 0x600001 dpy: 0xfd57d280
The VNC desktop is:      NAS:0
PORT=5900
```

Which is great!

But now how can I make x11vnc run without sudo so that it can run automatically using systemd?

This is my current `/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service`

```
# Description: Custom Service Unit file
# File: /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
[Unit]
Description="x11vnc"
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -loop -nopw -xkb -repeat -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever -rfbport 5900 -display :0 -auth guess
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Two more interesting links on this topic: [one with x11vnc](http://www.lueckdatasystems.com/Successfully_running_x11vnc_as_a_Systemd_Service_in_Xubuntu_16.04_Xenial-Xerus) and [one with TigerVNC](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-start-a-vnc-server-for-the-actual-display-scraping-with-tigervnc/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding `-auth /run/lightdm/root/:0` instead of `guess`, as this is the default path for quite a while now with most distros/display managers.

If this doesn't help, it seems there is a race condition despite the ordering you enforced via your service file. Maybe the display-manager service signals "ready" before everything is actually properly up. A not-so-nice-but-works workaround for that could be adding `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5` to your service to make sure X11 is properly up and running.

There is also libvnc.so from the TigerVNC package (`apt install tigervnc-xorg-extension`), which is a module you can load directly into your X11 server. In theory that should yield the best performance, but last time I tried it there were issues with some applications (like VMware Player) just displaying as a black window remotely.

Create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-vnc.conf` with content:

```
Section "Module" 
Load "vnc" 
EndSection

Section "Screen" 
Identifier "Screen0" 
Option "UserPasswdVerifier" "VncAuth" 
Option "PasswordFile" "/path/to/passwd" 
EndSection
```

Where `/path/to/passwd` was created via the `vncpasswd` command.